# Is INSERT INTO ... SELECT synchronous for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I make a scheduled query in Postgres through Airflow operator for inserting some aggregate from another table:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2)
SELECT ...
FROM table2
```

Downstream, I have another operator with query for checking size of table 1

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table1
```

Are these queries synchronous? Does the second query start strongly after first finish?
Or it can be a situation, in which second query start before all data inserted in `table1`?

Comment: They are not synchronous. Just think of a db where 1 insert would block all queries. Wrap both statements in a `BEGIN ... COMMIT;` block (cf. [PostgreSQL 12 Transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-transactions.html)).

Comment: The second (concurrent) statement will see the contents of `table1` as it was **before** the INSERT statement starte.

Comment: If I use `execute INSERT INTO .. SELECT` in PL/SQL, it willl become synchronous?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "synchronous"? Do you want the second statement to **wait** until the insert is finished?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes

Comment: Then you need to lock the table in exclusive mode before doing the INSERT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if I round both queries in `execute` statement, it will work as lock?

Comment: What do you mean by "*Downstream, I have another operator*"? I'm not familiar with Airflow, but it sounds like you are doing these two queries sequentially.

Comment: No, you need to use `lock table ..`

Comment: `LOCK TABLE` is a bad idea here.

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT` will run in a single database transaction, so until it is done, none of its effects will be visible outside the transaction.

So if the second query started before the first transaction finished, it will see none of the inserted rows. If it started after the first transaction completed, it will see all the rows.

In short: the second query will always see a consistent state of the database.